# Превращение физической памяти в оперативную

Tags: память, диск

Как какое-то количество памяти с жёсткого диска (допустим 4 гб) превратить в оперативную?

Comment: Да вряд ли... что это будет за "оперативная память" - мало того что недоступная процессору, так ещё и со временем доступа в миллисекунды?

Comment: @Akina, наверно, так заковыристо написано о swap-е.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ... или о readyboost... хотя кажется мне, что имеется в виду именно RAM.

Comment: Винда автоматически отхапывает себе несколько гигабайт диска C: именно под память

Comment: конкретный ответ зависит, от ОС

Answer (score 1):

**Хард превратить в RAM никак не получится.** По сути из-за скорости считывания и записи данных. [Вопрос уже поднимался на Toster.](https://toster.ru/q/362377) Даже если SSD, скорости отклика всё равно недостаточно. Да и в самих SSD распаяны чипы DRAM для кэша. Так что увы. :(

---

Зато наоборот - пожалуйста! Есть такая штука - [**RAM-диск**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) программная технология, позволяющая хранить данные в быстродействующей оперативной памяти как на блочном устройстве. [Можно сказать аналог SSD](https://habr.com/ru/company/kingston_technology/blog/395315/). Только скорость чтения и записи выше. Ну и кол-во RAM должно быть соответствующее. Например 128Gb.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Штука вообще весьма специфичная и я бы сказал узкозадачная, со своим вагоном минусов.

Comment: Какие вы педантичные. )) Так лучше?

Comment: Все же формат сайта обязывает ;-) И придется с вашим ответом поспорить, т.к. Windows ежесекундно превращает HDD в RAM - используя файл подкачки (swap).

Comment: @Kromster swap и замена памяти это разные вещи :) Возможно RAM и складыват излишек в swap когда подходит к концу. Что на обычных машинах бывает редко. Но при этом, в такие моменты начинаются тормоза, т.к. скорость чтения всё же ниже. И вот за счёт этого ограничения по сути и не получается осуществить полную подмену. ;) Это скорее мера предосторожности и исключение, чем норма.

Comment: О том и речь, что **превратить то можно**, но скорость будет катастрофически низкой.

Comment: @Kromster Можно в виде swap, а в том виде, в каком хочет автор ("мутация блинов в DRAM") - нет. ^_^ Как в сериале "Чёрный флаг" сцена с картиной. "Память? Память! Хранит? Хранит! Читать & Писать может? Может! Тоже самое мать твою!"))))